# Can the browserCaps web.config section be ignored by asp.net/iis?

Tags: web-config, browser

Can IIS/ASP.net ignore the browserCaps section in a web.config?

I have an app that on testing servers and dev environment IE8 is reported correctly - but in deployment IE8 is not recognised and content is rendedered "downlevel".....

do settings in web.config conflict with browsers.ini?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why this downlevel behaviour was happening. ASP1.1 has a bug where it will fail to recognise the browser when the BROWSER string is too long. Its not been fixed in 1.1, but 2.0 the browser recog works with the long string.

An interim step to get a 1.1 site working it to have a tool like ISAPI rewrite 'fix' the headers on the way in....